# Custom Network and Policy in Stable-Baselines3

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I am attempting to create a small working example of how to use MultiDiscrete actions spaces together with a Box observation space. One of the problems that I have run into is that the dimension returned by utilizing a normal policy does not fit with the Box dimensions. The base policy returns something of size 25, whereas I need something that is (5,5).

I have tried to alleviate this problem by generating a custom "policy" (actually a network) where I, as the last step, reshape the output to (5,5) rather than 25. This has resulted in an array of problems. I have attempted to read the documentation for how to create custom policies; however, I cannot for the life of me find the issue.

1. I have attempted to use policy_kwargs; however, I don't know how to write that the NN should be reshaped.
2. I have attempted to use a BaseFeaturesExtractor, with no luck as well.
3. Various combinations of 1 and 2.

I have included some of the error messages that I get for the various different attempts that I have made. Does anyone know what I am missing? Is it something completely fundamental that I have misunderstood?

```
import numpy as np
import gym
import torch.nn as nn
import torch as th
from stable_baselines3 import PPO
from stable_baselines3.common.torch_layers import BaseFeaturesExtractor  # don't know if this is necessary


# -------- Attempt using BaseFeaturesExtractor
# class CustomPolicy(BaseFeaturesExtractor):  # Don't know if BaseFeaturesExtractor is correct
#    def __init__(self, observation_space, action_space, features_dim: int = 25):  # Features should perhaps be (5,5)
#        super().__init__(observation_space, features_dim)
# --------

# Define a custom neural network architecture
class CustomPolicy():
    def __init__(self, observation_space, action_space):
        super().__init__()
        # Define the layers of the neural network

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(observation_space.shape[0], 64)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(64, 64)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(64, action_space.shape[0])

    # Reshape the output to match the Box observation space shape

    def forward(self, x):
        x = nn.functional.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = nn.functional.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        x = th.reshape(x, (5, 5))
        return x


# Define the grid world environment
class GridWorldEnv(gym.Env):
    def __init__(self):
        self.observation_space = gym.spaces.Box(low=0, high=1, shape=(5, 5), dtype=np.float32)
        self.action_space = gym.spaces.MultiDiscrete([5, 3])  # 5 movement directions, 3 movement distances

        self.state = np.zeros((5, 5))
        self.state[0, 0] = 1  # Start location
        self.goal = (4, 4)  # Goal location
        self.steps = 0
        self.state.flatten()

    def reset(self):
        self.state = np.zeros((5, 5))
        self.state[0, 0] = 1  # Start location
        self.goal = (4, 4)  # Goal location
        self.steps = 0
        return self.state.flatten()

    def step(self, action):
        direction, distance = action
        reward = -1
        done = False

        # Calculate the movement offset based on the selected direction and distance
        if direction == 0:
            offset = (distance, 0)
        elif direction == 1:
            offset = (-distance, 0)
        elif direction == 2:
            offset = (0, distance)
        elif direction == 3:
            offset = (0, -distance)
        else:
            offset = (0, 0)

        # Calculate the new position based on the current position and movement offset
        current_pos = np.argwhere(self.state == 1)[0]
        new_pos = tuple(np.clip(current_pos + np.array(offset), 0, 4))

        # Update the state with the new position
        self.state[current_pos] = 0
        self.state[new_pos] = 1

        # Check if the agent has reached the goal
        if np.argmax(self.state) == np.ravel_multi_index(self.goal, self.state.shape):
            reward = 10
            done = True

        # Increment step count and check if episode should end
        self.steps += 1
        if self.steps >= 50:
            done = True

        return self.state, reward, done, {}


# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create an environment with the CustomEnv environment
    env = GridWorldEnv()

    # Create policy
    policy = CustomPolicy(env.observation_space, env.action_space)

    # Create a PPO agent with the CustomPolicy
    model = PPO(policy=policy, env=env, verbose=1)
    # --------- TypeError: 'CustomPolicy' object is not callable

    # --------- Attempt at using policy_kwargs
    # policy_kwargs = dict(activation_fn=th.nn.ReLU,
    #                      net_arch=dict(pi=[32, 32], vf=[32, 32]))
    # model = PPO("MlpPolicy", env=env, verbose=1, policy_kwargs=policy_kwargs)
    # --------- ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (25,) into shape (5,5)

    # --------- Attempt at using policy_kwargs with custom policy
    # policy_kwargs = dict(
    #    features_extractor_class=CustomPolicy,
    #    features_extractor_kwargs=dict(features_dim=25), # should perhaps be (5,5)
    # )
    # model = PPO(policy=policy, env=env, verbose=1, policy_kwargs=policy_kwargs)
    # --------- TypeError: CustomPolicy.forward() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_sde'

    # Train the agent for 1000 steps
    model.learn(total_timesteps=1000)
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do the necessary reshaping in the env step function?

For example,

```
def step(self, action):
   action = action.reshape(5,5)
```